# Extract string between two strings in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have a sequence of strings like these:

```
val foo = Seq("bar scala baz", "bar java baz", "bar python baz")
```

I need to extract everything between `bar` and `baz` such that I get something like this:

```
val foobarbaz = Seq("scala", "java", "python")
```

How do I do this using regular expressions in Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
val regex = "^bar(.*)baz$".r
val foobarbaz = foo.collect { case regex(a) => a.trim }
```

Answer (score 8):

Not necessarily with regular expressions, consider `String` strip methods, like this,

```
foo.map { _.stripPrefix("bar").stripSuffix("baz").trim }
res: Seq[String] = List(scala, java, python)
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, it's possible to pattern match a `String`s by [unapplying a string interpolator](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/StringContext$s$.html#unapplySeq(s:String):Option[Seq[String]]):

```
// val foo = Seq("bar scala baz", "bar java baz", "bar python baz")
foo.map { case s"bar $lang baz" => lang }
// List("scala", "java", "python")
```